# XMLHttpRequest cannot load Joomla 2.5 | VM2

Tags: joomla-2.5, jquery, virtuemart

This is really strange... I receive this error in the console everytime I enter in the product details of some products (not all):

"xmlhttprequest cannot load no 'access-control-allow-origin'"

**Here's an image:**

[image]

I have tried to fix it adding to the htaccess file the next code:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

But it didn't work... Can anyone help me? I need help real fast... JQuery doesn't work in that part of the page because of that error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The reason you are getting this message** is stated in your image- you are trying to access http://benaventegrow.com from the website http://www.benaventegrow.com 
They look similar, but they are not the same. So why is this a problem?

> JavaScript code is limited by the same-origin policy, meaning, from a
>   page at www.example.com, you can only make (AJAX) requests to services
>   located at exactly the same domain, in that case, exactly
>   www.example.com (not example.com - without the www - or
>   whatever.example.com).

The link below explains what is going on much better than I can and is the source for the quote above.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20434788/691053

**How to fix?**

**Disclaimer:** I've never used virtuemart before- but what I would do is check the product entries in virtuemart for the products that give you the error. Check that the product entries contain **www** in the link. Example -> http://**www**.benaventegrow.com if they don't have it then add it.

Also it is a bad idea to use `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

> By responding with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * the requested
>   resource allows sharing with every origin. This basically means that
>   any site can send a XHR request to your site and access the server’s
>   response which would not be the case if you hadn’t implemented this
>   CORS response.

This is explained in more detail here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12014554/691053 and it is the source of the quote above.